# Check if argument in function is of a specific object

Tags: javascript, function, class, typechecking

How do I check that the passed in argument into a function is of the correct object?

Assume I make my own class "Person",
and I make a function that takes in a parameter, and checks that the parameter is that specific "Person" class.

How would I go about doing this in javascript?

Comment: You could use classes, and `instanceof`, but if you use Typescript, that uses Duck Typing and that's a bit more flexible in this area.   btw.   typechecking + Javacript = Typescript  :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. :) Whenever I googled and asked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `instanceof`.

In your case:

```
obj instanceof Person
```

This will return a boolean that tells whether the variable `obj` is of type `Person`